# extracting specific dir from tar file without creating the containing hierarchy

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar

Suppose a tar file have the following layout

```
$ tar -xvf test.tar -C test ./one/two/three

./one/two/three/
./one/two/three/four/
./one/two/three/four/file00.txt
./one/two/three/four/file01.txt
./one/two/three/four/file02.txt
./one/two/three/four/file03.txt
./one/two/three/four/file04.txt
./one/two/three/four/file05.txt
```

Is it possible to extract out only dir named "**four**" and it's content to specified dir.
But the dir **four** should be at immediate to the output dir mentioned.

```
$ tar -xvf test.tar -C test one/two/three
```

I've tried the above but the output dir **test** is containing all the folder hierarchy to dir four.

Comment: It cannot happen in one go; you'd need to `mv` the desired directory.

Comment: Yes I also think so...

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider pre-processing your `tar` archive with [tardy](http://tardy.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: no, in-fact I've heard of tardy for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for extracting only `./one/two/three/four/` directory:

```
tar -xvf test.tar ./one/two/three/four/
```

Comment: I want the destination dir should contain four at immediate level not inside ./one/two/three/four

Comment: It is because your original path itself is `./one/two/three/four/`. If you want you can do `mv` command after to suite your needs.

Comment: yes, But I was wondering if tar has some option for this too!

Comment: I don't think there is a tar built-in option of doing so.